# Сервер nginx не возвращает $remote_user (Laravel 5.8)

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, ldap

У меня на сайте происходит ldap-авторизация. Когда сайт залил на сервер, nginx не возвращает auth_user или $remote_user для определения данного пользователя.  А локально у себя определил юзера через get_current_user(). Вообще nginx имеет встроенный пакет авторизаций или нужно установить?

Comment: Очевидно, всё зависит от того, как вы сделали ldap и как настраивали nginx. Ldap на сервере сам по взмаху волшебной палочки не появится

Comment: для самого начала прочитайте хотя бы вводную часть хотя бы [википедийной статьи про ldap](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP).